# Clustered Web Services

Tags: web-services, jax-ws, cluster-computing

Is possible to do a clustered web service (with JAX-WS), that each node receives automatically the resources? May be with EJBs? If possible, how to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have a 2-node cluster on JBoss 5.1. On these node is deployed a WS via JAX-WS (JbossWS).

In JBoss is very simple to expose an EJB3 class and methods inside as Web Services. You only need to mark with annotations classes and methods you want to expose. All work without any deployment file. You can deploy the JAR file directly! :-)

Please refer to this page for other explanation: [JBossWS](http://www.jboss.org/jbossws)

I assure you: it works! We have it in production environment...